# How can I move the cursor to the end of the insertion? After using ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter()

Tags: delphi, ms-word

I am inserting into a word doc using the WordApp.ActiveDocument.Range.InsertAfter(). However after I do this the cursor is in the front position of the insertion. I have tried Insert After and Insert Before?  I have tried to copy to the clipboard and just paste but using this adds a #13 to the paste and I dont want that.  I just want the user of word to be able to hit a Fkey and automatically paste at that point some formatted text then continue at that point typing... any ideals? 
I am using Delphi 4 Pro.

Thanks Roy

Comment: @Roy: did the answer below answer your question? If not, let's keep working on it.

Comment: Thanks Otaku,
I was not able to try until this morning but I am still having a little trouble. I use delphi and have not got the format correct so far to do this. What value is Unit := WdStory? In Delphi I need to set the correct var.  Also I notice this method eliminates my formatting of the pasted text?  I set the copied data up in a richtext edit field so I can make some of it bold and diff font but when I insert the formatting is gone. I tried Win Messages but this does not find my doc. FindWindow(PChar('OpusApp'), nil);? Any Ideas? Thanks again. Roy

Comment: Sorry, in place of `wdStory`, in Delphi you would just write `6`. However, since you want to keep the formatting, `.InsertAfter` is not what you need, I'll update the code below for `Paste`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to move the insertion point after the range. The range is automatically re-sized when you do InsertAfter - you just move to the end and then select where you've moved to. Here's some VBA code to get you started:

```
Sub DoInsertAfter()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ActiveDocument.Range
    r.InsertAfter "something difficult to say in Arabic"
    r.Move Unit:=wdStory
    r.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Otaku, Was you able to come up with anything on this?  I have tried to paste myself but for what ever reasons I can not find the window using findwindow?  I also used this: 
{Find the main window of the Application}
//  g:=FindWindow(PChar('OpusApp'), nil);
//  g:=FindWindow('OpusApp',nil) ;
  {Find the window of the application's text box}
//  d:=ChildWindowFromPoint(g,point(50,50)) ;
  {Now send it a character!!}
//  SendMessage(g,WM_CHAR,Ord('A'),0) ;

It will find a Wordpad window but not a MS Office Word Window?
Any ideas?
Thanks Roy.

Comment: I forgot that I was able to use a paste command but not sendmessage. Like the insertafter but when I do the paste it will strip the last blank space and that is the way I was returning my font back to "NOT BOLD"  the pasted text is in bold and diff font. If the user continue to type it keeps this format? So I added that change in the pasted text but it scraps it before pasting???